# Postgresql: How to perform LIKE query on a json array?

Tags: json, postgresql, jsonb

I have a table with tags stored as a JSONB column. Like:

```
id   tags
---- ------------------------------
1    ["red", "blue"]
2    ["orange", "light pink"]
3    ["pink", "green"]
```

I'd like to select rows that contain tags that partially match a pattern -- in my case, I want tags with spaces in them. Something like `SELECT * FROM the_table WHERE tags LIKE '% %'`. Casting the array to text almost works, except everything matches because Postgres puts a space after commas in the output JSON.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the function [`jsonb_array_elements_text().`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-json.html)

```
with my_table(id, tags) as (
values
    (1, '["red", "blue"]'::jsonb),
    (2, '["orange", "light pink"]'),
    (3, '["pink", "green"]')
)

select *
from my_table, jsonb_array_elements_text(tags)
where value like '% %';

 id |           tags           |   value    
----+--------------------------+------------
  2 | ["orange", "light pink"] | light pink
(1 row)
```

Comment: How would one do a LIKE query against such array?

Comment: 'value' is the column containing the split text, where you'll have a row for each element in the array, joined with the row it came from.  So in the answer, `where value like '% %'` is finding the rows that contain spaces.